# I want to give longitude and latitude in Android studio and the my phone's gps jumps to that location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I want to give longitude and latitude in Android Studio and the my phone's GPS jumps to that location or input some GPX files so that I can travel to those location from Android Studio not by Android app. I need some help.

Comment: have you tryed it with android device monitor, I think you could do it there in the Emulator Contorl Tab

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Answer (score 0):

So, you just want to move the camera on a specific part of the map? 
Use

```
moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15));
```

where the 15 is the zoom.